# strip_tags and mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, strip-tags

I am using mysql_real_escape_string and strip_tags as follows:

```
strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($postvariable));
```

I just want to know if this makes sense. Will strip_tags still work, aka remove  tags and html tags after the string has been filtered by mysql_real_escape_string ?

Comment: No, it doesn’t make sense in most environments … as a user, I want to be able to _mention_ stuff like _“<b> and <strong> both make text appear bold”_, without the system idiotically stripping away the “tags” from that sentence.

Comment: Wow already -2 just for asking a question. @CBroe , Yes, I agree, however as a secure system I do not want users to be able to enter any markup.

Comment: Why not just test it out yourself?

Comment: [**Use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *end of story*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sure, I am doing that too. Jeez, did you even read my question.
iswinky I guess I'll have to.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_`, period. It's deprecated. If you feel it's been wrongly closed, tell me and I will reopen. Otherwise, it's a duplicate as SQL injection.

Comment: Dammit , I know how to prevent SQL injection, I AM USING PDO. I just wanted to know if combining the 2 functions makes sense. SO is USELESS !

Comment: *"Dammit , I know how to prevent SQL injection, I AM USING PDO. I just wanted to know if combining the 2 functions makes sense. SO is USELESS !"* - To answer: No, it doesn't make sense. If you're using PDO, then why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?  Those APIs do NOT mix. Plus, go easy on the language. Take a deep breath and count to 10; it works ;)

Comment: _“however as a secure system I do not want users to be able to enter any markup”_ – don’t _treat_ it as markup then, by escaping it properly when _outputting_ it into an HTML context. Look at [what `strip_tags` makes of f.e. `We know that 5<6 and 7>6 is true.`](http://3v4l.org/TI48u) – anyone who’s not completely bonkers would _not_ want that output from the given input. My advice: Just forget that this function even exists.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just wanted some advice.

Comment: @Janpan Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/). +1 for your avatar BTW. Slightly obscure, but great. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both are different and use are different as well, you can use them like

```
strip_tags($postvariable); //remove html tags

mysql_real_escape_string($postvariable); //it escapes special characters in a string
```